# Using async: true with ajax, what happens to the events triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I start an ajax request with async:true, I want to know what happens while the calls is happening. 
Two questions:

1. The other methods that are triggered in the meanwhile, are they queued? Can we be sure all of them will be executed, or do they timeout at some point?
2. If I click on a button that redirects me to another page, will the redirection wait for the ajax to finish? Or will the ajax call be aborted?

Comment: 1. if you really want to know what happens, read all about the javascript event loop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop ... 2. it will be aborted, javascript runs in the context of the page it's loaded in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The other methods that are triggered in the meanwhile, are they queued? Can we be sure all of them will be executed, or do they timeout at some point?

Yes, and yes. They are queued, and they will always eventually be executed.

> If I click on a button that redirects me to another page, will the redirection wait for the ajax to finish? Or will the ajax call be aborted?

When redirecting away from a page, most browsers will call the `onerror` callback with a status code of `0`.

For an extremely clear overview of the JS event loop, I highly recommend [this talk from Philip Roberts](http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html).